# Load view (other from the default) from AppDelegate.m

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I have a similar problem as the user "Flocked" (see question here: [Load an other View from applicationDidFinishLaunching in the AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997271/load-an-other-view-from-applicationdidfinishlaunching-in-the-appdelegate)), but after reading his post I didn't manage to work it out, maybe my situation is different from his.

I have inside my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` a routine for checking if the application is run for the first time (also taken from another user):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"everLaunched"]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"everLaunched"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstLaunch"];
    }
    else{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"firstLaunch"];
    }
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {

        NSLog(@"First run");
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I can't manage to load another view, `InfoView` (a view for setup) if firstLaunch occurs.
I have tried:

```
InfoView *infoView = [[InfoView alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:infoView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

inside `if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"])`

but no luck. Any ideas or help?

Comment: Are you entering the if condition correctly ? Do you see your NSLog ?

Comment: Yes,i dont have any issues with this.I am getting in when i delete the app from the emulator and build/run again. BTW i am not using Storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if (![defaults boolForKey:@"everLaunched"]) {
        NSLog(@"First run");
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"everLaunched"];
        InfoView *infoView = [[InfoView alloc]init];
        [self.viewController presentViewController:infoView animated:YES completion:nil];    
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Worked OK but i am getting " Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController: 0x6a74270>."

Comment: try setting `animated` to `NO` in presentViewController

Comment: Thank you all but especially phix23! This should help others too!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `[self presentViewController:infoView animated:YES completion:nil];` on `self`, which is of class `UIResponder` because you are in your `AppDelegate`. You should call it on a UIViewController, probably in your situation the *viewController*.

EDIT : This is the line to call, **after you call** `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` `otherwise self.window.rootViewController` will be nil.

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:infoView animated:YES completion:nil];
```